Problem inverting covariance matrices in Gaussian process
I am trying to understand how to compute the posterior probability of a Gaussian process. I am using a Matern kernel:
ker = GPy.kern.Matern32(10, ARD=True)  

The mean is given by:
K(xtest, xtrain) * K(xtrain, xtrain) ^ {-1} * ytrain

When trying to compute the second multiplication:
chunk = numpy.linalg.solve(ker.K(xTrain, xTrain), yTrain)

I get a singularity error, and in effect the determinant of ker.K(xTrain, xTrain) is zero.
What am I doing wrong here? Am I constructing the covariance matrices wrongly?
